# Algebraic_​loop_Solut​ion_SIMULI​NK

Tags: loops, simulink, flowchart

I want to implement the following pseudo-code in SIMULINK:

```
q^0 = q_init, i = 0
IF q^i ! = q_final
    q^(i+1) = q^i + alpha * F(q^i)
    i = i + 1
ELSE return <q^0,q^1 ... q^i>
```

The main problem is, that F(q^i) is a function of the current q and is calculated in every iteration. When trying to impement this in SIMULINK, I run into an algebraic loop that cannot be solved.

What is the proper way of solving the problem (in SIMULINK) ?

Thank you !

Miklos

Comment: Show us what you've done.  The equations themselves have no algebraic loop, so there must be something wrong with how you've implemented them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understand what to partition inside of a Simulink simulation and what should be the output.

You'd usually cache the outputs q^0 to q^i as outputs from the model, rather than trying to get the whole model to output that.

That means the Simulink model would just be dealing with calculating q^(i+1) from q^(i) (which you store with a unit-delay block).

Regarding the if condition: It is best not to run a simulation forever unless you know it will definitely tend towards q_final. If you're not using integers that might get very hard for the == to exactly evaluate. In that case you should use (abs(q^i - final) > threshold) then, and check it will end.

Ending a simulation exactly at that point might be possible with a breakpoint, but a simpler option would to allowing the simulation to run past it and then trim your output (q^0 to q^i, then some more values) in Matlab.

Comment: Thanks James ! I have also figured it out and done the same way. :) It's working.